# what's the path of geckodriver when selenium is executed by Cron

Tags: python, selenium, cron

I'm using Python to do some automated operation
And there is some worng when I using Selenium and cron
In this case,I using

**Selenium 3.141.0**

**Python 3.7.3**

**Mozilla Firefox 68.11.0esr**

**geckodriver 0.23.0**

I have moved geckodriver to this Path

```
geckodriver: /usr/local/bin/geckodriver
```

for my python script,I used this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
..........omission......
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

and saved it in my home directory as ***/home/xyz/script.py***
and my PATH is

```
-bash: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games: No such file or directory
```

when I test the script by ***./script.py***,It worked well.

but there is a error when I use Cron to execute it:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xyz/script.py", line 13, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

what's worng with the PATH of Cron,I think the file geckodriver is already in my PATH.

what should I do with it.

Comment: cron has a different path than you. Try putting it in /usr/bin